# Bash script. check the website is valid

Tags: bash, diff, lynx

I need to write a script that tells whether a given website ( first argument ) has been changed. I wrote something like that but it does not work and can not keep find an error

```
#!/bin/bash     

website=$1
time=$2    #frequency of checking the page
x=1
spr=$(diff -s ttt.txt ttt1.txt)
lynx -dump $website | cat > ttt.txt ttt1.txt
until [ 1 -eq 0 ]; do
    sleep $2
    lynx -dump $website | cat > ttt1.txt

        if [ "$(diff -s ttt.txt ttt1.txt)" = "$spr" ]
        then
            lynx -dump $website | cat > ttt.txt
            echo "Changes were made "

        else
            echo "No changes"

        fi
done
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are you getting an error? Is is never reporting changes? Always reporting changes? Something else entirely? Also piping through `cat` like that is pointless you can just redirect from `lynx` directly to the file.

Comment: It's never reporing changes.

Comment: You want `diff -q` or `cmp -s` for your change test for the record. There's no need to compare the output to any other output. What values do those files have when the script starts (i.e. what is the value of `$spr`?)?

Comment: files are empty , the variable spr is to store the value when the files are equal.

Comment: Then is your `if` test backwards? If `$spr` is the output when they are the same then when the new `diff` output is equal to `$spr` doesn't that mean there aren't any changes and when they differ that means changes were made?

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
lynx -dump $website | cat > ttt.txt ttt1.txt
```

Because you provide 2 files after the redirection, the shell sees this:

```
cat ttt1.txt >ttt.txt
```

So cat is reading from ttt1.txt, **not** from its stdin

---

demo:

```
$ cat > a <<END
hello
END
$ cat > b <<END
world
END
$ echo foo | cat > a b
$ cat a
world
$ cat b
world
```

"foo" is not stored to either file.